# In what way does non-"full n-key rollover" hinder fast typists?

Tags: usb, keyboard, typing, ps2, typing-speed

[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector#Legacy_port_status_and_USB) (although the latter claim does not cite a source) that:

> High-end keyboards that provide full n-key rollover typically do so via a PS/2 interface as the USB mode most often used by operating systems has **a maximum of only six keys plus modifiers that can be pressed at the same time.**[4] **This hinders fast typists,** ...

**In what way would the system being able to recognize only six non-modifier keys at once hinder a fast typist?**

I consider myself a relatively fast typist and I usually press *one* key, plus modifiers, at once; I can't imagine any real-life situation in which the system only recognizing six non-modifier keys being pressed at once has been a limiting factor in my keyboard usage. (Multi-*stroke* keyboard shortcuts as used by high-end software like Visual Studio, Emacs and the like are a different matter.)

Note that I am not really interested in answers centered around [multiplayer computer games](https://superuser.com/questions/43996/attaining-the-elusive-n-key-rollover?rq=1#comment44861_43997); I'm looking for answers that give reasons that would be relevant to *typists*, somehow supporting the statement made on Wikipedia.

Comment: Every time I read that I ask myself a similar question. I've come to the conclusion that it's 95% marketing for most, and maybe only a legit concern for those that play video games with tons of keybindings (say you're using arrows for one task, wasd for another, and a bunch of action keys for whatever WOW does). That's all my guess, nothing hard to prove it other than my experience never having a problem with my 6key limitation.

Comment: @nerdwaller That's pretty much my hope with this question; to draw out of the dark some actual reason for the claim. It might be a good or a bad reason as far as the reason itself goes, but surely somewhere, at some point, someone had *some* reason for making such a statement. I don't think "fast typists" are greatly affected by World of Warcraft keybindings, for one. :)

Comment: I've never really seen non-hipster keyboard fans complain about n-key rollover. A lot of those people use that as an excuse to claim PS/2 keyboards are better. Its keyboarder's vinyl ;p

Comment: You have to be *very* fast for six keys to be a hindrance. At some number, though a touch typist will see a hindrance. Remember, it's not when you're *trying* to push multiple keys simultaneously, it's when a finger is pushing a key before the other finger has fully released. If you try 'asdf' repeatedly with less than four key rollover, you will drop characters. Six keys should be fast enough for almost everyone.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't know if "140-wpm typer" qualifies as "hipster keyboard fan" but I can say without a doubt I have been personally affected by this many times. The n-key-rollover issue is the ultimate "gaslight issue" because the first several times the order jumbling happens, we blame ourselves. Only after it happens 10 times and we reproduce the issue do we realize it's the keyboard's fault. Also, it seems to happen way more often on Mac than Windows for some reason.

Comment: I'd refer you to  my more complete answer below to what I mean. Jumbled keys would be a different issue from lack of nkro in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Practically none unless you run into problems. *Most* keyboards are designed so keys commonly pressed together shouldn't interfere.

There's two aspects to this - keyboard matrixes (sometimes pressing two keys that share the same traces will interfer with each other) and the interface side of it. A keyboard with N key rollover will be more complex, and as such, least in theory, need more IO pins to read all the keys. As such it might be more expensive.

Early USB keyboards didn't support nkro - some folks claimed this was a reason that older PS/2 keyboards are superior. Modern keyboards sometimes do. In this case, well, its the keyboard geek equivilent of insisting vinyl is somehow magically better than a lossless digital recording of the same disk.

Microsoft has a [lovely explaination](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) on the keyboard matrix side of things and and a tool for testing it.

Practically *unless* you're a twitch gamer, who uses a load of macros, *and* is a complete keyboard geek, you shouldn't need to worry about NKRO

Comment: As someone who typed this entire comment in under an eighteenth of a second with one fluid motion, I must fervently disagree; full n-key rollover is vital to my day-to-day work.